# Silverlight ValidationSummary screen real estate

Tags: silverlight-3.0, grid, validationsummary

Silverlight 3;

I have a ValidationSummary in the top row of my grid. When the ValidationSummary appears, it pushes my button row (row 3) off the bottom of the displayable screen.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="36" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <di:ValidationSummary Grid.Row="0" />

        <Grid x:Name="gridOuterContentHolder"
              Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.68*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.32*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<!-- elements removed for brevity -->

        </Grid>

        <StackPanel x:Name="stack"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Content="Delete"
                    x:Name="btnDelete"
                    Height="20"
                    Width="75" />

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

I'm a code monkey not a pixel pusher and can't figure out which combination of Stretch's, Auto's and *'s I need. Any pushers out there that can help??

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by making the validationsummary control a child of scrollview with a maxheight set.  This limits the ability of the validationsummary to stretch beyond its parent's maxheight.

Because by default, validationsummary controls use a getparent() to determine the control they are validating, this requires you to manually override the target when the appication innitializes (in vb I do it in the new() routine of my page class.

```vb
MyValidationSummary.Target = TheNewGrid
```

You probably don't want to see the scrollviewer when there are no errors, so set it to Collapsed and in the make it visible only with the validationsummary has errors:

```vb
Private Sub MyValidationSummary_LayoutUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyValidationSummary.LayoutUpdated
    If MyValidationSummary.HasErrors Then
        svMyValidationSummary.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
    Else
        svMyValidationSummary.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
    End If
End Sub
```

I can't seem to get this editor to not screw up the xaml, here's a link:
[example](http://dumpz.org/18428/)

```xml
<ScrollViewer Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="svMyValidationSummary" MaxHeight="200" Margin="6" BorderThickness="1">
    <dataInput:ValidationSummary FocusControlsOnClick="True" x:Name="MyValidationSummary"></dataInput:ValidationSummary>
</ScrollViewer>

<data:DataGrid Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="1250" x:Name="TheNewGrid"  Height="350">
    <data:DataGrid.Columns>
        <local:DataGridTemplateColumnBindingText  CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False"
                          HeaderStyle='{StaticResource RowHeaderColumnStyle}' >
            <local:DataGridTemplateColumnBindingText.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controlsToolkit:DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <StackPanel controlsToolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button ToolTipService.ToolTip="Insert an empty row" Click="btnInsertRow_Click">
                                <Image Source="add.png"></Image>
                            </Button>
                            <Button ToolTipService.ToolTip="Copy row" Click="btnDuplicateRow_Click">
                                <Image Source="application_double.png"></Image>
                            </Button>
                            <Button  ToolTipService.ToolTip="Delete row" Click="btnDeleteRow_Click">
                                <Image Source="delete.png"></Image>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="PowderBlue">
                            <TextBlock controlsToolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Left" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding SortNumber}"></TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </controlsToolkit:DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:DataGridTemplateColumnBindingText.CellEditingTemplate>
        </local:DataGridTemplateColumnBindingText>
    </data:DataGrid.Columns>
</data:DataGrid>
```